# Android: How to dynamically place views with relative spacing

Tags: android, android-layout

I am dynamically placing views into a RelativeLayout.  Currently, I am doing:

```
layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(0, position, 0, 0);
relativeLayout.addView(textViewInstance, layoutParams);
```

where `position` is incremented by a fixed amount after each `TextView` object is added to the layout. The problem is that some of the `TextView`s contain long strings, which makes for awkward formatting on devices with smaller screen sizes because the string will spill into multiple lines and bleed into the whitespace.

Is there any way I can add these `TextViews` with spacing relative to the `TextView` right above it?  I want to achieve something to the effect of:

```
layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(0, previousTextViewInstance.bottomPixel + 50, 0, 0);
relativeLayout.addView(textViewInstance, layoutParams);
```

where `previousTextViewInstance` will be saved after each new `TextView` is added.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could use a table layout...

Comment: You know, that is an excellent point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting margin for each view, you can dynamically add each view below the previous one in relative layout.

For that, first set an id for each of your textView.

```
firstTextView.setId(textView_id_1);
```

while adding second textView, set rule for layout params as:

```
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textView_id_1);
secondTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
secondTextView.setId(textView_id_2);
```

Comment: Thanks...is there any way to specify something like RelativeLayout.BELOW+(some amount of pixels)?  I don't want all the text to be right up against each other.

Comment: adding rule as RelativeLayout.BELOW will set you view below the previous view. And to set margin use .setMargins(0, requiredMargin, 0, 0);

Comment: And as every view should be below previous consider using LinearLayout with vertical orientation (and still setting margin). Then you won't have BELOW rule